# 'Ryan Reynolds ... admitting to Entertainment Weekly that he went “nipples akimbo”'

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does “[nipples akimbo](https://www.dailystar.co.uk/showbiz/us-showbiz/sandra-bullock-confirms-ryan-reynolds-30591982?int_source=amp_continue_reading&int_medium=amp&int_campaign=continue_reading_button#amp-readmore-target)” mean in the following phrase? This [link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/akimbo#:%7E:text=1,tailor%20sitting%20with%20legs%20akimbo) says it can mean "having the hand on the hip and the elbow turned outward" or "set in a bent position", but I don't know which of the two definitions should be applied here. Thank you!

'Ryan was involved in a naked fight scene for the movie, admitting to Entertainment Weekly that he went “nipples akimbo”'.

Answer (score 0):

The word "akimbo" is normally only used to describe the position of arms and legs.

In both cases, it means they are bent outwards, then back inwards, so hands on hips with elbows out is "arms akimbo", and knees apart with feet together is "legs akimbo".

"Akimbo" is sometimes used in other contexts to mean two things held outwards in mirror image to each other, as in "Guns Akimbo", a Daniel Radcliffe movie where he spends most of the movie holding one pistol in each hand.

"Akimbo" doesn't really mean anything in that phrase. Ryan Reynolds is a comedian and was probably making a joke about being naked, since you cannot bend your nipples into any shape, but imagining Reynolds doing so is funny.

Comment: People [other than me] also use akimbo to mean 'every which way', or 'in random directions'. It's possible he's using it that way - nipples everywhere, in all directions; presumably only done by moving your body around a lot, rather than having nipples like chameleon eyes ;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I think you're right. If you can come up with some verification for that, like a definition or other examples, it would make a great answer, probably better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

From comments…

People [other than me] also use akimbo to mean 'every which way', or 'in random directions'.
It's possible he's using it that way - nipples everywhere, in all directions; presumably only done by moving your body around a lot, rather than having nipples like chameleon eyes ;)

From my built-in Apple dictionary, second definition

> #### akimbo | əˈkɪmbəʊ |
>
> **adverb**
>
> - with hands on the hips and elbows turned outwards: she stood with arms akimbo, frowning at the small boy.
> - (with reference to limbs) flung out widely or haphazardly: he collapsed on the bed, legs akimbo.